# Is it allowed for formatted input/output functions to raise floating-point exceptions?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, language-lawyer, c11

Sample code (t0.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%e\n", 1.0f);
    {
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
        return fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

If `1` is returned, then is it an error?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  What should happen if you passed a trap representation?

Comment: Because conceptually how writing output to the stream can cause floating-point exceptions? Re: _if you passed a trap representation_: UB?

Comment: Merely accessing some values [leads to undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p5): "Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Somewhere inside `printf` it has to convert the binary number to decimal.  That requires a lot of floating-point arithmetic.  Is it reasonable to think the library programmers could write that code in such a way that it would never raise an exception, no matter the input?

Comment: @NateEldredge I was thinking of disabling/enabling OR saving/restoring FP exceptions at the enter/exit of formatted input/output functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Even more: not just "allowed", but "required".

IEEE 754-2019, 5.12.2:

> If rounding is necessary, they shall use correct rounding and shall correctly signal the inexact and other exceptions.

ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E) working draft— December 11, 2020 N2596, Annex F.5:

> The "inexact" floating-point exception is raised (once) if either conversion is inexact.392) (The second conversion may raise the "overflow" or "underflow" floating-point exception.)

> The specification in this subclause assures conversion between IEC 60559 binary format and decimal character sequence follows all pertinent recommended practice.